ASP.NET MVC web app solution folder has codetemplate cs.t4 for controller, view, area, etc and how to check whether it is used?
An ASP.NET MVC web app on the .NET Framework 4.7.1 has codetemplate cs.t4 in its solution folder, for controller, view, area, etc.
How to check whether it is used?
Please advise
